# CakePHP pagination custom url

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to implement pagination with custom url, when i try to paginate to the next page i am getting the following error.

The requested address '/adminuser/userlist/page:2' was not found on this server.

Here adminuser is the name of the admin user and userlist is the method to get all the users under this adminuser.

The url will look like this http://domain.com/adminuser/userlist

Here is my code

```
In view:

<?php $this->paginator->options(array('url' => 
array('path'=>$this->params['path']))); ?>
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li class="prevnext disablelink">
       <?php echo str_replace('/users/','',$this->paginator->prev('« Prev'));?>
        <li>
        <?php  echo str_replace('/users/','',$this->paginator->numbers());?>
        </li>
        <li class="prevnext">
        <?php  echo str_replace('/users/','',$this->paginator->next('Next »'));?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/:sluguser/:action', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'userlist'),array('pass' => array('sluguser')));
```

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, using the default `'paramType' => 'named'` you will need to extend your route to accept also the `page` parameter (as well as `sort` and `direction`). In your `routes.php`, you can add following:

```
// Parse only default parameters used for CakePHP's pagination:
Router::connectNamed(false, array('default' => true));
// the route to your controller action and wildcard (*) for the possible named parameter
Router::connect('/:sluguser/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'userlist'),array('pass' => array('sluguser')));
```

Btw. As I have found out recently named parameters are deprecated and totally [removed in CakePHP 3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#named-parameters), so  consider using `$this->paginate['paramType'] = 'querystring';` instead. Then it will work without those additional routes above.

Comment: thanks for the response, i have made the changes in the routes.php file as you mentioned, now my error has gone, but my url looks different like this http://domain.com/adminuser/userlist/userlist/page:4 . the action appears multiple times.

Comment: ok, then check, what is inside your `$this->params['path']`, I guess there is twice `userlist`. Besides I don't find `path` as standard cake's sub option for `url`, is it your own helper extension? Or use instead `$this->paginator->options(array('url' => 
array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'userlist', 'sluguser' =>  $this->request->params['sluguser'])));`

Comment: If i use action and wildcard (*) it's affecting my other routes

Comment: Yeah it is possible. Try to place this route as a last one (in routes.php), it will make sure that it will catch first those direct routes (without passed args).